# Linux alias chain commands (can recursion be avoided?)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias, tcsh

I've been looking around for ways to alias clear and ls into one command.
Currently I've defined command x:

```
alias x="clear;ls"
```

Now is there any walkaround to avoid recursion and define:

```
 alias ls='clear;ls'
```

Comment: I can't get it to do anything recursive on my system, but have you tried `alias ls='clear;/bin/ls'`?

Comment: My `ls` has long been an alias referring to 'ls' and, like Manny D, it's never had recursion problems.  I tried your `alias ls='clear;ls'` and it worked fine also.  This is on RHEL 5 Linux, with Bash version 3.2.25 -- what kind of system and what shell are you using?

Comment: oh I was using tcsh, if I define: alias ls `'clear;ls'` and use ls it will throw an `"Alias Loop."` error. But it worked under Bash.

Comment: Perhaps you should change the `bash` flag to `tcsh` then.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you put a backslash before the command name, that will disable any aliases.

```
alias ls='clear;\ls'
```

Or, like Arnaud said, just use the full path for ls.

Comment: I think that this is the cleanest solution and it works just fine. Thanks

Comment: Likewise, quoting will disable the alias.  This is true within an aliasdefinition and also as a direct command.

Answer (score 20):

Another way of doing this would be

```
alias ls='clear; command ls'
```

This is different from `/usr/bin/ls`, as it still searches `ls` in the `$PATH`, but will ignore shell functions or aliases.

Comment: This is applicable to many situations, not just aliases.  If you want to go straight to built-ins and executables, bypassing functions and aliases, use the `command` built-in.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct recursion in alias.  From man bash:

> The
> first word of the replacement text is tested for aliases,  but  a  word
> that  is  identical to an alias being expanded is not expanded a second
> time.  This means that one may alias ls to ls  -F,  for  instance,  and
> bash  does  not try to recursively expand the replacement text.

Nonetheless, you can also note:

> The first  word  of  each
> simple  command, if unquoted, is checked to see if it has an alias.  If
> so, that word is replaced by the text of the alias.

```
$ pwd
/Users/myhomedir

$ alias ls="date;pwd"
$ ls
Fri Jun 23 16:34:00 PDT 2023
/Users/myhomedir


$ alias pwd='whoami'
$ ls
Fri Jun 23 16:35:00 PDT 2023
enzyme

$ alias ls="date;'pwd'"
$ ls
Fri Jun 23 16:35:38 PDT 2023
/Users/myhomedir
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do :

```
alias ls='clear;/usr/bin/ls'
```

When typing:

```
$ ls
```

First of all it will search an user defined function, it will launch it, else search in $PATH commands.

By giving the explicit path of the `ls` command, recursion will be avoided.

Comment: It is funny because ls is never in /usr/bin.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `ls` with `--color=auto` parameter ( `-G Enable colorized output.`) and like to use functions.

```
clear_and_ls() {
    clear
    command ls --color=auto
}

alias ls="clear_and_ls"
```